# Why is random_state required for ridge & lasso regression in sklearn?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

In scikit-learn, Lasso and Ridge regression are two regression methods which have a `random_state` attribute. Why do these two methods need this attribute?

From the documentation:

```py
class sklearn.linear_model.Lasso(alpha=1.0, fit_intercept=True, normalize=False, precompute=False, copy_X=True, max_iter=1000, tol=0.0001, warm_start=False, positive=False, random_state=None, selection=’cyclic’)


class sklearn.linear_model.Ridge(alpha=1.0, fit_intercept=True, normalize=False, copy_X=True, max_iter=None, tol=0.001, solver=’auto’, random_state=None)
```

Comment: Please *format* your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of [lasso](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html), RNG can be used (depending on other selected options) to randomly select features for which to perform updates:

> The seed of the pseudo random number generator that selects a random feature to update. If int, random_state is the seed used by the random number generator; If RandomState instance, random_state is the random number generator; If None, the random number generator is the RandomState instance used by np.random. Used when selection == ‘random’.

In the case of [ridge](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html), RNG can be used (depending on other selected options) for shuffling data:

> The seed of the pseudo random number generator to use when shuffling the data. If int, random_state is the seed used by the random number generator; If RandomState instance, random_state is the random number generator; If None, the random number generator is the RandomState instance used by np.random. Used when solver == ‘sag’.

Answer (score 4):

Both methods involve the generation of random numbers at certain stages for the the models.

For the Lasso this is due to the fitting of the regression coefficients of each variable. This can be done in a 'cyclic' way, or selecting variables at random at each iteration. The attribute `selection = 'cyclic'` for the first and `selection = 'random` for the latter. The latter involves random numbers. As the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html) states:

> If set to ‘random’, a random coefficient is updated every iteration rather than looping over features sequentially by default. This (setting to ‘random’) often leads to significantly faster convergence especially when tol is higher than 1e-4.

For Ridge regression, it is required in case you want to fit the model using stochastic gradient descent, which makes use of subsampling. To do so you need to state during initialization of your model `solver = 'sag'` or `solver = 'saga'`. The [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html) at `random_state` reads:

> The seed of the pseudo random number generator to use when shuffling the data. If int, random_state is the seed used by the random number generator; If RandomState instance, random_state is the random number generator; If None, the random number generator is the RandomState instance used by np.random. Used when solver == ‘sag’.